# @api.constrains is not working properly

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In the 'project.project' model I wrote a function to validate 'start Date' and 'end date' for this I used onchange function.The function is working and giving warning but record is creating. Actually if there is any error means record cannot be saved because I am using @api.constrains below is my code.

py.code:

```py
@api.onchange('date','date_start')
@api.constrains('date','date_start')
def cheking_field_date(self):
    self.t1 = self.date_start 
    self.t2 = self.date
    if self.t2 == False:
        pass
    else:   
        if str(self.t1) > str(self.t2):
            raise Warning('The Deadline Date is Invalid')
        else:
            pass
```

But When I was Editing the record if any change in date field means than everything is fine(i.e. validation problem in 'start date' and 'end date').At that time the record is not saving.Why this type problem is coming can any one help me please.

Answer (score 5):

You need to take care of following points:

- No need to use *@api.onchange*
- Remove unnecessary variables.
- Write only condition that you want to raise warning.

Try with following code.

```py
@api.one
@api.constrains('date','date_start')
def cheking_field_date(self):
    if self.date_start and self.date:
        if self.date_start > self.date:
            raise Warning('The Deadline Date is Invalid')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not working same problem was coming.

Comment: Have you compare both date value ? I think as per condition, it will not allow to save record. So might be problem in data.

Comment: I tried same function in 'project.task' but it is working fine.The problem is with 'project.project' model.I tried with your code also but no use

Comment: That's what I mentioned. There is problem with data.

Comment: Here I am getting 'start date' and 'end date' data and function is also working fine and showing the alert. But the problem is @api.constrains is not working

Comment: Constrains will fire when we save record. If you want to raise warning or display any message then I would suggest to use *onchange()* to allow save record. Constrains will not allow to save record if it's raise warning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156613/discussion-between-phani-and-odedra).

Comment: Just using `@api.constains(...)` is enough. No need to use any @api.one, and especially `@api.onchange`.

Comment: @tidylobster: I am agree with your comment which is perfect for Odoo10. But as per my knowledge, we need to write `@api.one` in Odoo 8.